# Pod affinity to nodes with the same label

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling, kube-scheduler

I am in situation where number of nodes is reasonably large. Nodes are consumable and can be added and removed (if idle) at any time.  All nodes would have labels

> label.category=A or
> label.category=B

I want to schedule my pods onto nodes with the same category. I really do not wish to hardcode which one. All I want is that a group of pods would end up in the same category nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may wanted to use Pod Topology Spread Constraints, as example below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: mypod
spec:
 topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: <integer>
      topologyKey: <string>
      whenUnsatisfiable: <string>
      labelSelector: <object>
```

Comment: topologyKey is the secret souce. Thank you very much. I wish I could upvote your answer several times.